# FileZilla3 cannot connect

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am using FileZilla ftp client since many years. Current version is 3.43.0 The problem is that using version 3.XX I cannot connect to one of my storage -> netgear stora with vsFTPd 2.0.7 server (Passive ports are opened from the router). The error I got is:

```
Status: Resolving address of MY-IP
Status: Connecting to MY-IP:2121...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.7)
Command:    USER XXX
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS 
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

From the same computer I can connect using: windows ftp clients, WinSCP, even FileZilla v2.

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to MY-IP:2121 ...
Status: Connected with MY-IP:2121. Waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.7)
Command:    USER video
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8 OFF
Response:    UTF8 ON
Response:   211 End
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/...."
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CDUP
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/...."
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD XXX
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/...."
Status: Directory listing successful
```

In FileZilla3 options I set "Encryption" tab to Only use plain FTP (insecure)

I am not sure but few weeks ago it was working. Didn't make any changes - ftp server, router settings. Also tried to downgrade the FileZilla version to few previous, but no success. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show us a log file from any working FTP client.

Comment: Status: Connecting to MY-IP:2121 ...
Status: Connected with MY-IP:2121. Waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 (vsFTPd 2.0.7)
Command: USER niki
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS **********
Response: 230 Login successful.
Command: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Response: 211-Features:
Response:  EPRT
Response:  EPSV
Response:  MDTM
Response:  PASV
Response:  REST STREAM
Response:  SIZE
Response:  TVFS
Response:  UTF8 OFF
Response:  UTF8 ON
Response: 211 End
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD

Comment: Edit the log into your question

Answer (score -1):

I think I found solution.
FileZilla v.3 client -> settings -> connection -> Increase timeout seconds do 30-35.
I don't know why server become... slower.

Comment: It makes no sense. Your question does show any problem with a connection or a timeout. Your log shows that the server responded with `530 Login incorrect`. That cannot be caused by a short timeout.